# Quick question on structure groups of the frame bundle of a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles

Let $M$ a manifold and $G$ a group.

Is it true that the statement: "the structure group of the frame bundle of $M$ can be reduced to $G$" simply means:

There is a subbundle $S$ of the frame bundle  (i.e. at each point some distinguished set of frames, e.g. the orthogonal ones) and an atlas of $M$ such that the transition functions map $S$ to $S$?

If yes, why is this equivalent to $M/G$ having a global section?

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold and $E_M$ it bundle of frames. Recall that if $x$ is an element of $M$, and $T_xM$ its tangent space, a linear frame at $x$ is an inveritble linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow T_x$. We denote by $E_M(x)$ the set of linear frames at $x$, and by $E_M\cup_{x\in M}E_M(x)$, $E_M$ is a $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$-principal bundle. It can be reduced to $G\subset Gl(n,\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to saying that there exists a trivialisation $(U_i,g_{ij})$ of $E_M$ such that $g_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow G$, this implies the existence of a $G$-principal bundle $E_G\rightarrow M$ whose coordinate change are $(U_i,g_{ij})$.

Consider $E_M/G$, it is the bundle over $M$ which is obtained by gluing $U_i\times Gl(n,\mathbb{R})/G$ with $U_i\cap U_j\times Gl(n,\mathbb{R})/G \rightarrow U_i\cap U_j\times Gl(n,\mathbb{R})/G$ $(x,y)\rightarrow (x,\bar g_{ij}(x)(y))$ where $\bar g_{ij}(x)$ is the map induced by $g_{ij}(x)$ on $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})/G$ by $g_{ij}(x)$. If there exists a $G$-reduction, $g_{ij}(x)\in G$ and $\bar g_{ij}(x)$ is the identity, we deduce that $E_M/G$ is trivial, and henceforth has a global section.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is really hard to read and hard to understand. As far as I understood you, that $E_M$ can be reduced means that we can find trivializations  such that the transition functions map to a subgroup $G$ in $Gl(n,\mathbb R)$. This differs from what I wrote. Hence a question: Does being able to be reduced to $G$ imply that there is a set of frames invariant under $G$?

Comment: Regarding the second part: So we take trivializations with transition functions in $G$. Then modulo $G$ the transition functions are trivial, so the bundle is trivial. When looking at example of reduction of the frame bundle, for example almost complex manifolds allow a reduction to $Gl,(n/2, \mathbb C)$ or simplectic manifolds allow reduction to the simplectic group, there always is a special tensor ($I$, $\omega$). Can they be used in order to define a global section?

Comment: Does being able to be reduced to G imply that there is a set of frames invariant under G and vice versa?